# -[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001afa700 error on non-initial launch. Google Translate MLKit

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, google-mlkit

I am trying to add Google MLKit Translate into my SwiftUI Project. I am already using firebase via SPM and only after the initial launch get this error: `-[FBLPromise HTTPBody]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001afa700`

Here is my code:

App Delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ...
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        ...
        let spanishRemoteTranslator = TranslateRemoteModel.translateRemoteModel(language: .spanish)
        if ModelManager.modelManager().isModelDownloaded(spanishRemoteTranslator) {
            print("Spanish Translator Downloaded")
        }else {
            print("Downloading Spanish Translator")
            
            ModelManager.modelManager().download(spanishRemoteTranslator, conditions: ModelDownloadConditions(allowsCellularAccess: true, allowsBackgroundDownloading: true))
        }
        return true
}
```

Then I call it like so:

```
if ModelManager.modelManager().isModelDownloaded(spanishModel) {
    Translator.translator(options: englishSpanishTranslator).translate(buis.name!) { translatedText, error in
        if error == nil {
            if let translatedText = translatedText {
                name = translatedText
            }else {
                print("error = \(error)")
            }
        }else {
            print("error = \(error)")
        }
    }
}else {
    print("error = Spanish not downloaded")
}
```

I have also tried using the built in FirebaseMLKitDownload and that doesn't have translator. What is going on?

Comment: The GitHub repo has a couple of similar issues that contain potential solutions, did you have a look at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9251, for example?

Comment: @PeterFriese Ok. However, does that also mean that I have to use cocoapods for firebase?

Comment: No - you can use SPM for Firebase.

Comment: @PeterFriese no I can’t. According to that github issue. There is a duplicate dependency and that is causing the issue

Comment: Oh, is it because MLKit requires you to use CocoaPods?

Comment: Yes. That’s exactly it

Comment: Yes, ML Kit does not currently support SPM yet, so you will have to use cocoapods for both ML Kit and Firebase, to avoid mixing cocoapods with SPM and having duplicate dependencies, as reported in the github issue.

Answer (score 3):

Probably an author of this post found solution of this problem ([judging by the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731600/fblpromise-httpbody-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x600001afa700-er#comment126789003_71731600)) but I decided to write this post because few hours ago during taking my first steps with Firebase I had the same error. I hope my post may be helpful for each other.

I had no idea how to find solution but after few hours of debugging I noticed that the problem occurs when I had initialized project with Firebase using dependency manager built-in in the Xcode and then I tried to initialize Firestore using CocoaPods. To be more specific, first thing I do was Firebase installation using this one:

[image: Xcode package dependencies manager]

Then, I started using CocoaPods like:

```
$ pod init
$ vim Podfile // adding 'firebase/firestore' dependency or specific line from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk
$ pod install
$ open <ProjectName>.xcworkspace
```

In the next step, I tried to check basic Firestore operations like creating collection and documents with data and when I run the app - I got similar error. It was an exception during app run.

I think in my case the problematic thing was possible duplicates because of supplying the project with a Firebase (with all dependencies) twice.

So, I removed dependency installed from the Xcode manager. In my `Info.plist`  there is no dependencies:

[image: Xcode project Info.plist]

Then, from the terminal I removed `Pods` directory and just called an update.

```
$ rm -rf Pods
$ pod update
```

All dependencies were re-installed and workspace has been recreated.
Now, after these steps everything works fine.

Comment: I just kind of gave up

Comment: I am also having this problem and am ready to give up anytime soon